# Does gradient descent for linear regression selects the minimal norm solution?

Tags: classification, linear-model, loss-functions, max-margin

I was told that *Gradient Descent finds the weights of smallest norm*.

This is what I understood in the **linear *regression*** setting:

$f_w(x)=w^\top x$ are the linear functions $ \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.

$ \mathcal{D}=\{(x_i,y_i) \in \mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R} \mid i=1,...,n\} $ is a dataset

Then I choose some loss function $L$, then some cost function $C_0$ such that
$ C_0(w)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_i L(f_w(x_i),y_i) $

Finally, I defined a regularized cost $ C_\lambda(w)=C_0(w)+\frac{\lambda}{2n}||w||^2 $

Then there must be some sort of equivalence between (and it looks it should be some classical result):

1. minimizing $C_\lambda(w)$ for an opportune $ \lambda \ge 0 $
2. minimizing $C_0(w)$ **with Gradient Descent**

My questions:

- Can somebody clarify a bit this fact? By providing some hypothesis (e.g. on $L$), some insight, some reference...
- Does this apply in a similar way to the **linear classification** setting ($y_i\in\{-1,+1\}$)? In that case, I would expect some equivalence bewteen:

1. maximizing $M(w)= \min_{i=1...n} y_i \langle w, x_i \rangle $ over $||w||=1$
2. minimizing $||w||$ over $ y_i \langle w, x_i \rangle \ge 1 $
3. maybe the previous 1. and 2. points above (those regarding regression)

Comment: too many questions in one post. can you break them down?

Comment: Well it's 2 questions, and they're related. Even some hints or some links would be helpful.. Please also note that the first half of the post is common knowledge.

Comment: If you know about the topic you can probably answer right away without effort